# Dead spot in Android screen - can't press some keys

Tags: keyboard, touchscreen

There's a dead spot on the right of my Nexus 4. It interferes with pressing some keys.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Your screen is broken you need to buy a new one. Even if it's not showing any scratches.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I've found is to use the SwiftKey keyboard but [choose the "compact" layout](https://support.swiftkey.com/hc/en-us/articles/201591331-How-to-change-your-keyboard-mode-on-Microsoft-SwiftKey-for-Android).

[image]

Then by pressing on the arrow, shift it to the other side, and resize it to the maximum.

Works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Is your screen broken in even the slightest bit? It is very common for an LG phone screen to become unresponsive when broken. Also, is the phone second hand? If so it might have had the screen replaced which could have installed a defective screen into your unit.

If either of these are true i would recommend replacing the screen. It is a relatively easy repair.